# SVG Unwanted Padding

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using SVG for the first time.  I got my SVG files from https://simpleicons.org/.  However I have a problem that the SVG seems to have some sort of unwanted padding around it.  After many hours of trying to work out what is going on myself, I still can't, so am reaching out to this community.  Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

```css
svg {
width: 64px;
height: auto;
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: middle;

}
svg:hover {
  fill: #a48322;
}
```

```html
<div><svg role="img" viewbox="0 0 64 64" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M23.954 4.569c-.885.389-1.83.654-2.825.775 1.014-.611 1.794-1.574 2.163-2.723-.951.555-2.005.959-3.127 1.184-.896-.959-2.173-1.559-3.591-1.559-2.717 0-4.92 2.203-4.92 4.917 0 .39.045.765.127 1.124C7.691 8.094 4.066 6.13 1.64 3.161c-.427.722-.666 1.561-.666 2.475 0 1.71.87 3.213 2.188 4.096-.807-.026-1.566-.248-2.228-.616v.061c0 2.385 1.693 4.374 3.946 4.827-.413.111-.849.171-1.296.171-.314 0-.615-.03-.916-.086.631 1.953 2.445 3.377 4.604 3.417-1.68 1.319-3.809 2.105-6.102 2.105-.39 0-.779-.023-1.17-.067 2.189 1.394 4.768 2.209 7.557 2.209 9.054 0 13.999-7.496 13.999-13.986 0-.209 0-.42-.015-.63.961-.689 1.8-1.56 2.46-2.548l-.047-.02z"/></svg><txt>Follow on Twitter</txt></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewBox is larger than the drawing. If we change that and then make the width and height smaller, we get rid of the padding.

```css
svg {
width: 24px;
height: auto;
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: middle;

}
svg:hover {
  fill: #a48322;
}
```

```html
<div><svg role="img" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M23.954 4.569c-.885.389-1.83.654-2.825.775 1.014-.611 1.794-1.574 2.163-2.723-.951.555-2.005.959-3.127 1.184-.896-.959-2.173-1.559-3.591-1.559-2.717 0-4.92 2.203-4.92 4.917 0 .39.045.765.127 1.124C7.691 8.094 4.066 6.13 1.64 3.161c-.427.722-.666 1.561-.666 2.475 0 1.71.87 3.213 2.188 4.096-.807-.026-1.566-.248-2.228-.616v.061c0 2.385 1.693 4.374 3.946 4.827-.413.111-.849.171-1.296.171-.314 0-.615-.03-.916-.086.631 1.953 2.445 3.377 4.604 3.417-1.68 1.319-3.809 2.105-6.102 2.105-.39 0-.779-.023-1.17-.067 2.189 1.394 4.768 2.209 7.557 2.209 9.054 0 13.999-7.496 13.999-13.986 0-.209 0-.42-.015-.63.961-.689 1.8-1.56 2.46-2.548l-.047-.02z"/></svg><txt>Follow on Twitter</txt></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the `viewbox` to 24 makes the box smaller. And you can increase the width/height to `64px` if that is the size you wish the icon to have.

```css
svg {
width: 64px;
height: 64px;
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: middle;

}
svg:hover {
  fill: #a48322;
}
```

```html
<div><svg role="img" viewbox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M23.954 4.569c-.885.389-1.83.654-2.825.775 1.014-.611 1.794-1.574 2.163-2.723-.951.555-2.005.959-3.127 1.184-.896-.959-2.173-1.559-3.591-1.559-2.717 0-4.92 2.203-4.92 4.917 0 .39.045.765.127 1.124C7.691 8.094 4.066 6.13 1.64 3.161c-.427.722-.666 1.561-.666 2.475 0 1.71.87 3.213 2.188 4.096-.807-.026-1.566-.248-2.228-.616v.061c0 2.385 1.693 4.374 3.946 4.827-.413.111-.849.171-1.296.171-.314 0-.615-.03-.916-.086.631 1.953 2.445 3.377 4.604 3.417-1.68 1.319-3.809 2.105-6.102 2.105-.39 0-.779-.023-1.17-.067 2.189 1.394 4.768 2.209 7.557 2.209 9.054 0 13.999-7.496 13.999-13.986 0-.209 0-.42-.015-.63.961-.689 1.8-1.56 2.46-2.548l-.047-.02z"/></svg><txt>Follow on Twitter</txt></div>
```